# aSmack File Transfer Returning NPE

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

im am Developing a Chat app, at the FileTransfers, i can successfully send file to a spark client, but at the listening, i am receiving NullPointerException error at the negotiating part, here is the IQ received by android client from spark:

```
 RCV (0): <iq id="dnkUY-33" to="reza@reza-hp/Smack" from="admin@reza-hp/Spark 2.6.3"  
 type="set">
 <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="jsi_5267323957851897853" 
 mime-type="image/jpeg" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-
 transfer">
 <file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" 
 name="635px-Food.jpg" size="45135">
 <desc>Sending file</desc>
 </file><feature 
 xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
 <field var="stream-method" type="list-single">
  <option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option><option>   
  <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option></field></x></feature> 
  </si></iq>
```

and here is the error Printed:

```
   07-01 13:40:49.075: W/System.err(1986): java.lang.NullPointerException
   07-01 13:40:49.075: W/System.err(1986):  
   atorg.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.
   IncomingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(IncomingFileTransfer.java:173)
   07-01 13:40:49.075: W/System.err(1986):  at  
   org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.
   IncomingFileTransfer.access$100(IncomingFileTransfer.java:45)
   07-01 13:40:49.075: W/System.err(1986):  at  
   org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.
   IncomingFileTransfer$1.run(IncomingFileTransfer.java:122)
   07-01 13:40:49.085: W/System.err(1986):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

the Exception is null, but According to the IQ provided, it seems transfer Type is a " Stream Initiation " , so i thought may be asmack doesnt discover it by default, does any one has any solution for this, or knows how to discover "Stream Initiation" ? thanks alot in advance <3
oh and im using OpenFire server :)

Comment: OOOkkk, just found the solution, i was Right about the problem, am sorry for aSmack's weak IT, just add this field :
    

    ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol 
    /si");


so your aSmack supports the StreamInitiation.... am sure this Solves alot of ppl's problems

Comment: also in some cases you might need to add this to the sending side:

      

      FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);

or/and:

      FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY=true; //note that this causes to use only IBB   
      protocol, but some times no choice depending on client, server etc, due to asmack  k
      known bugs

Comment: "just add this field : ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addFeature("jabber.org/protocol /si");" This is done automatically by aSmack. Also there are "known aSmack bugs" related to file transfer. Which version are you using?

Comment: latest version 8-4.0.0, obviously its not

Comment: and dude, does openfire support offline file transfer?

Comment: The 'http://jabber.org/protocol/si' namespace is added to the connections features once a FileTransferManager is initiated: FileTransferManager() calls FileTransferNegotioator.getInstanceFor() which calls FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled() which adds the feature to the ServiceDiscoveryManager.

Comment: i also have added that, still didnt work untill i did as i said

Answer (score 0):

OOOkkk, just found the solution, i was Right about the problem, am sorry for aSmack's weak IT, just add this field :

```
 ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addFeature("jabber.org/protocol  
 /si");
```

so your aSmack supports the StreamInitiation.... am sure this Solves alot of ppl's problems

also add file transfer providers AFTER connection, it makes difference. and by that i mean when ever you are sure they are readen when connection is already connected like "try"

and most important part : use Asmack 8-4.0.0 rc-1 for sure,Best suited for file transfers any questions ill be glad to help, after 1 fckin week trying i think i learnt alot. thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest not to use a release candidate (4.0.0-rc1) of aSmack when the release is available (4.0.0). There is no reason to use the -rc1.

Comment: dude have you found any absolute solution for asmack file transfer?

Comment: I've no problem with aSmack filetransfer, it works for me and therefore I'm not looking for a solution.

Comment: well may you help me a little, as much as i know the code has no problem, did u test it with emulator and openfire server?

Comment: because with the same code, my code occasionaly works, and then doesnt after restarting app !

Comment: if anybody got solution than please can help me, my chat app with ejabberd server and between android clients working properly but when i send any file than the progress of sending stucks at 0.0..what could be the reason?